# split and expand.grid by group on large data set

Tags: r, split, expand

I have a `df` in the following format and try to get a dataframe with all the pairwise combinations per group

```
df<-structure(list(id = c(209044052, 209044061, 209044061, 209044061,209044062, 209044062, 209044062, 209044182, 209044183, 209044295), group = c(2365686, 387969, 388978, 2365686, 387969, 388978, 2365686, 2278460, 2278460, 654238)), .Names = c("id", "group"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

While `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$group), function(i) expand.grid(i$id, i$id)))` works for a small data frame I run into time problems on my large data (~12 million obs. and ~1.5 million groups).

After some testing I recognized that the split command seems to be the bottleneck and expand.grid might also not be the fastest solution.

Found some improvements for expand.grid [Use outer instead of expand.grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405637/use-outer-instead-of-expand-grid)
and some faster split alternatives here [Improving performance of split() function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297843/improving-performance-of-split-function-in-r) but struggle to put it all together with grouping.

Output should be something like

```
  Var1      Var2
209044061 209044061
209044062 209044061
209044061 209044062
209044062 209044062
209044061 209044061
209044062 209044061
209044061 209044062
209044062 209044062
209044295 209044295
209044182 209044182
209044183 209044182
....
```

As an extra I would like to exclude repetitions of the same pair, self-reference (e.g. above `209044061 209044061`) and only keep one combination, if they are in different orders (e.g. above `209044061 209044062`and `209044062 209044061`) (**Combinations without repetitions**). Tried `library(gtools)` with 'combinations()` but could not figure out if this slows down the calculation even more.

Comment: Potentially `data.table`? `library(data.table);
setDT(df)[, expand.grid(id, id), by = group]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution which avoids repetitions of the same pair as well as different orders is using the `data.table` and `combinat` packages:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(id), data.table(combinat::combn2(unique(id))), by = group]
```

> ```
>      group        V1        V2
> 1: 2365686 209044052 209044061
> 2: 2365686 209044052 209044062
> 3: 2365686 209044061 209044062
> 4:  387969 209044061 209044062
> 5:  388978 209044061 209044062
> 6: 2278460 209044182 209044183
> ```

`order(id)` is used here just for convenience to better check the results but can be skipped in production code.

#### Replace `combn2()` by a *non-equi join*

There is another approach where the call to `combn2()` is replaced by a non-equi join:

```
mdf <- setDT(df)[order(id), unique(id), by = group]
mdf[mdf, on = .(group, V1 < V1), .(group, x.V1, i.V1), nomatch = 0L,
    allow.cartesian = TRUE]
```

> ```
>      group        V1        V2
> 1: 2365686 209044052 209044061
> 2: 2365686 209044052 209044062
> 3: 2365686 209044061 209044062
> 4:  387969 209044061 209044062
> 5:  388978 209044061 209044062
> 6: 2278460 209044182 209044183
> ```

Note that the non-equi join requires the data to be ordered.

#### Benchmark

The second method seems to be much faster

```
# create benchmark data
nr <- 1.2e5L # number of rows
rg <- 8L # number of ids within each group
ng <- nr / rg # number of groups
set.seed(1L)
df2 <- data.table(
  id = sample.int(rg, nr, TRUE),
  group = sample.int(ng, nr, TRUE)
)

#benchmark code
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  combn2 = df2[order(group, id), data.table((combinat::combn2(unique(id)))), by = group],
  nej = {
    mdf <- df2[order(group, id), unique(id), by = group]
    mdf[mdf, on = .(group, V1 < V1), .(group, x.V1, i.V1), nomatch = 0L,
        allow.cartesian = TRUE]},
  times = 1L)
```

For 120000 rows and 14994 groups the timings are:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
>  combn2 10259.1115 10259.1115 10259.1115 10259.1115 10259.1115 10259.1115     1
>     nej   137.3228   137.3228   137.3228   137.3228   137.3228   137.3228     1
> ```

#### Caveat

As pointed out [by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937866/split-and-expand-grid-by-group-on-large-data-set/46938294#comment80836042_46938294) the number of `id` per `group` is crucial in terms of memory consumption and speed. The number of combinations is of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, exactly *n* * *(n-1)* / *2* or `choose(n, 2L)` if *n* is the number of ids.

The size of the largest group can be found by

```
df2[, uniqueN(id), by = group][, max(V1)]
```

The total number of rows in the final result can be computed *in advance* by

```
df2[, uniqueN(id), by = group][, sum(choose(V1, 2L))]
```

Comment: run into `negative length vectors are not allowed` which is due to memory? @Uwe

Comment: Have you tried the non-equi join version? Using the artificial benchmark data with 12 M rows, 1,5 M groups it took 14 seconds without memory issues. What is the maximum number of `id` per `group`, e.g., `df2[, uniqueN(id), by = group][, max(V1)]`?

Comment: Wow worked out now. The hint to check for the id per groups helped. The biggest group (200000 ids per grp) was too much to handle I assume bc once I took it out your code run through. Maybe that could be an addition as future OPs might run into this large group problem

Comment: I have added a caveat to check the size of the largest group and to compute the number of rows in the final result *in advance*. Thanks for suggesting.